# JPanels horizontally not lining up when trying to use FlowLayout.LEFT on the components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

So my GUI, I have 1 JPanel in the red box called Connection that has 2 other panels north and south. Im using FlowLayout and trying to set the Host and Port label to line up on the left side but they are off by a bit and cant seem figure out why.

```
public class ClientView extends JPanel {

private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
private JButton connect;
private JTextArea display;
private JTextArea text;
private JTextField host;
private JTextField text1;
private JButton send;

// Constructor for all the components of the GUI for the Client application
public ClientView() {
    // Sets the layout for the Client application and the border
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    JPanel connectionPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    JPanel clientRequestPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    JPanel subDisplayPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane displayPanel;
    JLabel hostLabel = new JLabel("Host: ");
    JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Port: ");
    String ports[] = new String[]{"", "8088", "65000", "65535"};
    // Makes a ComboBox and gives its requirments. Makes it the color white, editable and size
    comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(ports);
    comboBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    
    comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(4);
    comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 25));
    // Makes the Connect Buttons and gives it the color red.
    connect = new JButton("Connect");
    connect.setBackground(Color.RED);
    connect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 25));
    // Sets the host labels required dimensions of 40 and 25. Then the JTextField host with its text being localhost
    // Also makes it White, editable, size and its margin
    hostLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 25));
    host = new JTextField("localhost");
    host.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    host.setEditable(true);
    host.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(490, 25));
    host.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0));
    // Sets the port labels required dimensions of 40 and 25
    portLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 25));
    // Creates the send button makes it uneditable and its dimension
    send = new JButton("Send");
    send.setEnabled(false);
    send.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 25));
    // Sets the mnemonic for the letter H for the host label
    hostLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('H');
    // Aligns the hostLabel to the left
    hostLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    // For when ALT-Key is pressed that it focus is transfered
    hostLabel.setLabelFor(host);
    // Sets the mnemonic for the letter P for the port label
    portLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('P');
    // Aligns the portLabel to the left
    portLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    // For when ALT-Key is pressed that it focus is transfered
    portLabel.setLabelFor(comboBox);
```

[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 4) I tend to use `FlowLayout` ***only*** when I have a single row of components. Simply, easy, predictable. I'd *probably* use `GridBagLayout` for this.

Comment: BTW - *"red box called Connection that has 2 other panels north and south."* Are we looking at the same GUI? The red panel in the screen shot is in the north, with black in the center.

Comment: So by default BoxLayout makes the center JPanel to fill the rest of the frame, and I needed the Display Panel to be the biggest so What I did is added the connectionPanel and the requestPanel to a Panel thats north while connectionPanel having a north and south Panel. So the north panel has 4 panels in it while the south part of the frame is just the one display Panel. Its hard to explain but I should of made my variable names more clear to identify.

Comment: I still see no MRE / SSCCE, so I've voted to close and am closing this tab in the browser. Let me know if you make an [edit] to fix that.